# $getJSON results with jquery .push() and mustache.js

Tags: jquery, getjson, mustache

I have this script that I thought would push each new item returned by the $getJSON ajax request to an array. The array would then be used by mustache.js for templating. Here's what that looks like:

```
$(function() {

var templateData = new Array();

$.getJSON('views.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        templateData.push({
            name : item.name
        })
    });
});
console.log(templateData);



var galleryTemplate = $('#gallery-template').html();


$('body').append(Mustache.render(galleryTemplate, templateData));
```

});

I can see in the console that items are not being pushed to the array. There aren't any errors on the page but nothing is being rendered on the front end, which looks like this:

```
<body>
   <script id="gallery-template" type="text/html">
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
   </script>

   <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-mustache.js"></script>
   <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is an async call, so it's executing after your `console.log`… and your render. Move all of those lines inside the `$.getJSON` callback, just after your `$.each` call.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('views.json', function(data) {
        var templateData = [];

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            templateData.push({
                name : item.name
            })
        });

        console.log(templateData);

        var galleryTemplate = $('#gallery-template').html();

        $('body').append(Mustache.render(galleryTemplate, templateData));
    });
});
```